# How to test whether service is working using pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I have a piece of code, which I have to test using pytest:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

# two decorators, same function
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index.html')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', the_title='Tiger Home Page')

@app.route('/symbol.html')
def symbol():
    return render_template('symbol.html', the_title='Tiger As Symbol')

@app.route('/myth.html')
def myth():
    return render_template('myth.html', the_title='Tiger in Myth and Legend')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

As I have not been dealing with pytest before, I do not know how to do it. I was looking for similar questions, but nowhere did I find any hints. Could someone give an example or materials how to test the above application?

Comment: I found this documentation on google [unittest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html)

Comment: Start by clearly specifying what you want to test. Typically you should think of tests in the form "for input X, I expect output Y". Describe all of your tests in English before attempting to write them in code.

Comment: @B.Gees Note that unittest is not the same thing as pytest.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, I discover a new stuff, tyvm :)

Comment: [Testing Flask Applications](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/testing/) from Flask docs is a complete tutorial on writing Flask tests with `pytest`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of concepts here. But I'll try to cover the basics. You need to specify which type of test you want to do. The most common are:

- Unit Tests
- Integration Tests
- Acceptance Tests

The idea of a unit test is to test the behavior of a specific function or method. It will mock (return fake data) every dependency of that function and try to isolate it to ensure that whenever I provide the data X it will always return what I'm expecting.

An integration test, on the other hand, tests exactly what the unit tests try to avoid: the integration between functions, services, and so on. It is a more advanced concept and way harder to test.

At last, an acceptance test will ensure that the business logic is working. So, it will try to do something with your application and ensure that it is doing what you want it to do.

There are a lot of other types of tests, but those are the most common.

Aboout testing routes, you can do both unit and acceptance tests. I don't think a unit test is useful there, because the logic in the route function is always really simple.

You can try the following snippet to run an acceptance test in a route:

```
from <your module name> import app

def test():
    app.testing = True
    result = app.post('path_you_want_to_test',
                      data=<data_you_want_to_test>,
                      follow_redirects=True)
```

With that you will get the result of that post request in the result variable.